# How can I get result as struct? (gorm)

Tags: mysql, go, orm, go-gorm

My Category Entity is

```
type Category struct {
    CategorySeq       uint   `json:"categorySeq" gorm:"primaryKey; column:category_seq"`
    CategoryName      string `json:"categoryName" gorm:"column:category_name"`
    CategoryParentSeq uint   `json:"-" gorm:"column:category_parent_seq"`
    CategoryLevel     int    `json:"-" gorm:"column:category_level"`
}
```

The result struct as I want get data as

```
type ProductCategory struct {
    Category1 Category `json:"category1" gorm:"embedded"`
    Category2 Category `json:"category2" gorm:"embedded"`
    Category3 Category `json:"category3" gorm:"embedded"`
}
```

And my database data is

```
table : category
category_seq | category_nanme | category_parent_seq
1                first                  0
2                second                 1
3                third                  2

table : product
product_seq | category_seq
1                1
```

The result I want unmarshal Json as

```
"category": {
  "category1": {
  "categorySeq": 0,
  "categoryName": ""
 },
  "category2": {
  "categorySeq": 0,
  "categoryName": ""
 },
  "category3": {
  "categorySeq": 0,
  "categoryName": ""
 }
},
```

But I don't know how to get category result considering with parent_seq
so I try to use sql query like this

First I tried to select result as this struct

```
type CategoryRes struct {
    CategorySeq1  uint   `json:"categorySeq1,omitempty" gorm:"-"`
    CategoryName1 string `json:"categoryName1,omitempty" gorm:"-"`
    CategorySeq2  uint   `json:"categorySeq2,omitempty" gorm:"-"`
    CategoryName2 string `json:"categoryName2,omitempty" gorm:"-"`
    CategorySeq3  uint   `json:"categorySeq3,omitempty" gorm:"-"`
    CategoryName3 string `json:"categoryName3,omitempty" gorm:"-"`
}
```

and use this orm query to get result as CategoryRes struct

```
func GetProductCategory(productSeq uint) *products.CategoryRes {

    categoryRes := new(products.CategoryRes)

    err := orm.GetData().
        Model(&products.Category{}).
        Select(
            `category.category_seq AS CategorySeq3, category.category_name AS CategoryName3,
            c2.category_seq AS CategorySeq2, c2.category_name AS CategoryName2,
            c3.category_seq AS CategorySeq1, c3.category_name AS CategoryName1`,
        ).
        Joins("LEFT JOIN product p ON p.product_category = category.category_seq").
        Joins("LEFT JOIN category c2 ON category.category_parent_seq = c2.category_seq").
        Joins("LEFT JOIN category c3 ON c2.category_parent_seq = c3.category_seq").
        Where("p.product_seq = ?", productSeq).
        Find(&categoryRes).Error

    print(categoryRes)

    if err != nil {
        print("error category")
    }
    return categoryRes
}
```

but it is not mapping any fields...
I don't know why
If you give me hint It will very helpful to me.

Comment: How come `CategoryRes` doesn't have tags for gorm, but the other structs do?